# I am not getting the out put file for the below sql batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file, output

```
@echo off

set sql_exe="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql.exe"
set sql_options=-user root -password amma
set sql_db="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data\aview"
set count=1

for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.sql) do (
  echo %%a > temp.sql
  call :processtemp_sql
)
goto :eof

:processtemp_sql
%sql_exe% %sql_options% -i temp.sql -o output%count%.txt %sql_db%
set /A count=%count%+1
goto :eof

:eof
```

---

input.sql has a sql query

select * from status;

Comment: `select * from status;`  ?  would you please ask something more  ?

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea about MYSQL syntax - and the on-line manual isn't much help.... but since you've gone to the trouble of establishing `sql_db` - shouldn't you be using it somewhere?